# Design a score page in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I want to design a score page that have 2 parameters an string and a number

so now I implemented a listview .and first I put string and between them space and then number

but i have a problem and that is when the string size is changed in second score then

the form not look like good.
I am new to Android So everyone can Help me

score xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/images"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <include 
        android:id="@+id/headerbar"
        layout="@layout/header" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/headerbar"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#00F0FF"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and my code is:

```
Master master = new Master();

    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
    data.clear();
    data = master.Recs();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Records.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
    lv.setAdapter(null);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

so data is a arraystring that like : "jack         2500"

so next time other name is:          "jay        2760"

so its not look like good and I want every time 
distance between name and number be a equal distance that text in left side of screen and number in right side showen

sorry for bad english

thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if we can work your problem out, especially not without at least a little bit of your code.

Answer (score 0):

U can use 2 TextViews side by side both to store other values.

Comment: no space not work correct
i want a score page like is in RacingMoto game